# Select only one field where equals "z"

Tags: mysql

I want to query a database so that I get **all** fields where field = x, all fields where field = y and **only one** field where field = z in only one query so I can obtain something like this:

> (...) content = something,  field = x
>
> (...) content = something,  field = x
>
> (...) content = something,  field = x
>
> (...) content = something,  field = x
>
> (...) content = something,  field = y
>
> (...) content = something,  field = y
>
> (...) content = something,  field = z (only one field where field = Z)

I tried using distinct but it wouldn't work. Any idea on this one? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(select * from your_table where field in ('x', 'y'))
 union all
(select * from your_table where field = 'z' limit 1)
```

Comment: @Namezito: what do you mean by everything, as the query does exactly what you described.

Comment: Are you not happy with the order (because his query does what you asked for)? If so do 2 UNION ALLs; 1st WHERE field='x', 2nd WHERE field='y', and the 3rd WHERE field='z' limit 1. Good luck.